# Rails_admin do not show all included models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have Rails app with some models, frontend and administration with rails_admin. I have these rails_admin settings:

```
# Config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  ...
  config.included_models = %w[ User Page Event Link Slide Main Partner ]
  ...
end
```

But it's not working, it show only Events, Links, Pages. I do not know where I did mistake.

Comment: I looked forever for this, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you using CanCan with rails admin?
Maybe you haven't set the ability model to make them manageable.

Or maybe you haven't restarted your server.

Comment: I feel like a child :-D my mistake. CanCan problem with abilities